# Trying to loop over index values - Intend to to get False value for every index number divided by 2

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list such as:

bool_list = [False,False,True,True,True,True]

Now I plan to run a for loop to make sure that every index value divided by 2 gets converted to False. In case, the index value is not divided by 2 then it remains the same.

For example, I want a result in which the bool_list will display =

[False,False,False,True,False,True] as the 2nd and 4th index has been turned to False.

I have tried to write the following for loop using the enumerate function to get the index value but somehow it's giving me an error:

```
def mark_false(bool_list, p):
    for idx,val in enumerate(bool_list):
        if idx % p ==0:
            bool_list[idx] ==False
        else:
            bool_list[idx] = bool_list[idx]
    return (bool_list)
```

The function is going to be with p = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a loop by replacing the slice of every other index with a list of `False` objects of the same length:

```
>>> bool_list = [False,False,True,True,True,True]
>>> bool_list[::2] = [False] * len(bool_list[::2])
>>> bool_list
[False, False, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what your are looking for. 
just changes 4th and 6th element of bool_list.

```
def mark_false(bool_list, p):
    for i in range(2 * p, len(bool_list), p):
        bool_list[i] = False
    return bool_list
print(mark_false(list_true(6), 2))
```